# Google Big Query - Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been having the error:

> An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

Since an hour and cannot use Big Query since then even with very simple queries on public dataset like:

```
SELECT * FROM [fh-bigquery:bigdataspain.aggr_transaction_clean] LIMIT 1000
```

From Googling around it seems to be a back end issue. How is it possible to reset the app?

Comment: Post your job id so an engineer can verify it.

Comment: Very similar issue explained here: stackoverflow.com/a/35070229/133864

Answer (score 1):

Check [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/)
It shows BigQuery Service Disruption today

You don't need to reset anything